# Difference between gradient and normal vector of a curve

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, vectors

What is the difference between the gradient of the tangent line and a normal vector of a curve? I understand they mean different things, but the equations are very similar.

For example, I want to find the gradient and normal vector for the curve x^2+y^2=25 at the point (3, 4). Won't I get the same vector, <6, 8>, for both? If not, where does my error lie?

Comment: What do you mean by the *directional derivative* of a curve?

Comment: @UmbertoP., sorry. I'm still very unfamiliar with the concepts, I meant the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The $\textit{gradient}$ is a defined for functions, and not for lines or curves: it is the differential of a function $f$ which takes values in $\mathbb{R}$. Its matrix at each point in the standard basis is given by the vector $\nabla_pf=\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\right)$ (I suppose you are working in $\mathbb{R}^2$).

On the other hand, the normal vector to a curve at a given point is an unitary vector orthogonal to the tangent vector. If your curve is defined by an equation $f(x,y)=0$, it is possible to show that the normal vector at a point $p$ points exactly in the same direction that the gradient vector of $f$ at $p$.

To see that take a local parametrization $(x(t),y(t))$ of your curve such that $(x(0),y(0))=p$. Then you have $$f(x(t),y(t))=0$$ for every value of the parameter $t$. Deriving both sides of the preceding equality (you can apply the chain rule in the left-hand side) and evaluating in $0$, we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p)\cdot x'(0)+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\cdot y'(0)=0,$$ which can be written as $$\left(\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(p),\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(p)\right)\cdot(x'(0),y'(0))=0.$$ Now observe that $(x'(0),y'(0))$ is a vector contained in the tangent line (by the definition), so $\nabla_pf(p)$ is perpendicular to that line, that is, it has normal direction.